# Return on activity A since end activity D with keep back on activity B ans C

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button, activity-finish

I have 5 activities (A, B, C and D).

A -> B -> C -> D

- On activity B and C, if we press the return button, I would like the previous activity to be called (respectively A and B).
- Activity D is an end activity without a return button.
  When I use "finish ()", it's currently going back to Activity C.

I would like to go back directly to activity A when we reach activity D by executing finish() without going through B and C.

However since B I must always be able to return to A and too C can back to B.

- "A" is an activity in launchMode singleTop.
- `android: noHistory = true` on activity D does not allow me to return directly to A.

The only solution I have found for the moment is to use startActicity (A) instead of "finish ()" but I find that this solution is not a good pararique.

Do you have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your D activity use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourFirstActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

This way, you'll return exactly to your A activity.

Comment: He want to return activity A from D but **keep** B, C in the backstack. With your code, it will remove B, C from the backstack.

Comment: No, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Once on D, I do not want to access B or C.

Comment: Yep! Because it's senseless to keep B and C in backstack, they both will recreate, if you will go to them from A activity once again ))) But, you should use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() to save B and C activitys' state, if you need ))) Have a happy coding!